# "Natural" embeddings of free groups in general linear groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

There are many embeddings of the free groups $\mathbb{F}_n$ into $GL_m(\mathbb{Z})$. An often encountered example for $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the Sanov subgroup generated by

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\;\text{ and }
\;
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

But an example that one could consider particularly "natural" is the commutator subgroup generated by

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
-1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
\;\text{ and }
\;
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix},$$
since it follows from a group theoretic construction.

Hence my question: what would be a natural choice of embedding for $\mathbb{F}_n$ when $n>2$?

Comment: If $\langle x,y\rangle$ is a "natural" embedding of $F_2$, then $\langle x^iyx^{-i}: 0\le i<n\rangle$ is a "natural" embedding of $F_n$.

Comment: I agree, this seems reasonably natural.
Thank you.